# Is it possible to send feed to update the listing in foursquare?

Tags: foursquare, bing-api, bing-maps, yelp

I have to correct/update our business listing in foursquare, axciom, yelp.

Is it possible to send the updates through API to correct that? If yes please give me a suggestion. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change data on foursquare venues through the api using this method: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/edit. The full list of editable attributes is on that link.